# No longer have tokens after updating Nano S

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum, ledger-nano-s

I recently updated my Nano S and was required to reset everything. After udpdating I went to MEW to swap my KIN & I had a ETH Ballance of 0.000 & a KIN ballance of 0.000. I have the address copied of my wallet that I've sent everything to which shows the ballance on Etheerscan. How do I retrieve the tokens/ get them back into my Nano?

Answer (score 1):

Your balance is not in your Nano, your balance is in your *wallet*. Nano is an interface, so is MEW and Etherscan.

Be sure to use the correct *derivation path* when you unlock your wallet. This may be the issue. Also, let your interface to scan and synchronize with the blockchain, perhaps because you reset, it lost the history and takes time to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Ledger Nano S uses a non-standard derivation path to confuse everyone and make it annoying to use on many dapps that assume a derivation path, such as decentralized exchanges. Ledger uses `m/44'/60'/0'/0` instead of `m/44'/60'/0'`. Ledger does do a lot of things they probably shouldn't security wise, but that's a different discussion.

In short, don't use Ledger Live if you don't want this annoyance in the future. MyEtherWallet can manage both paths, but is more laborious to use.